# Weak convergence and trace operator

Tags: sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

Suppose that $u_j\rightharpoonup u$ in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ (notice the **weak** convergence), with $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ regular enough. Let $v_j=Tu_j$, and $v=Tu$, where $T:W^{1,p}(\Omega)\to L^p(\partial \Omega)$ is the trace operator. Can I claim one of the following?

1. $v_j\rightharpoonup v$ in $W^{1-\frac{1}{p},p}(\partial \Omega)$
2. $v_j\to v$ in $L^p(\partial \Omega)$

In my case $p=4/3$, so I think the first implies the second. But what I really need is simply the second one.

Edit: the fractional exponent for the trace Sobole space is $1-\dfrac{1}{p}$, not $\dfrac{1}{2}$ (unless $p=2$, obviously).

Edit 2: I read somewhere (can't find the link/reference now) that a valid norm for for traces is

$$
\|u\|_{W^{1-1/p,p}(\partial \Omega)} := \underset{Tv=u}{\inf} \|v\|_{W^{1,p}(\Omega)}.
$$
It looks to me like a legit norm, and with this characterization, we have that $T$, as an operator from $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ onto $W^{1-1/p,p}(\partial\Omega)$ is continuous, with norm $1$. If this is correct, then, as Jose said in a comment, 1. would be true.

Comment: Since $T:W^{1,p}(\Omega)\to W^{1-1/p,p}(\partial \Omega)$ is linear and continuous, the first assertion is true.

Comment: But on every book the operator $T$ is said to be linear and continuous from $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ to $L^p(\partial \Omega)$. I can't find any claim of it being of it being linear (well, this is obvious) and continuous onto $W^{1-1/p,p}(\partial \Omega)$. Do you have any link/reference?

Comment: If your claim is true, though, then yeah, 1. follows immediately.

Comment: DiBenedetto's books "Real Analysis" and "Partial Differential Equations" both have it if I recall correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look to those.

Comment: For the second assertion, if $W^{1-\frac{1}{p},p}(\partial\Omega)$ is compactly embedded in $L^p(\partial\Omega)$ ,then the weak convergence from 1) is transformed to a strong one, so 2) will hold.

Comment: So is (2) correct ?

Comment: In this case, yes. If $(k-\ell)p<n$, the immersion of $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ into $W^{\ell,q}(\Omega)$ is compact whenever $q<q^*$, with $1/q^*=1/p - (k-\ell)/n$. In this case, $n=2$ (since we are on $\partial \Omega$ and $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^3$), $\ell=0$ and $k=1-1/p=1/4$, so $q^*=8/5$.

Checking the actual number is not really necessary, since $q^*>p$ (whenever $(k-\ell)p<n$).